# How can i manage google authentication for enter password in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-authentication, react-component, google-authenticator

Thanks for you help.

Here, What I have tried!, Please help me out to have the functionality, when i enter the first digit then it should move to next, and so on.., We should also have the back functionality.

Note : I Don't want to use any npm for this, need custom logic.

HTML/UI Code :

```
<form className="readmin-form custom_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this))} id="googleAuth">
                            <div className="row">
                                <span>Note : Please enter your Google Authentication Code below.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-2 mt-2">
                                            <Field name={'pin1'}
                                                    maxLength={"1"}
                                                    normalize={isInteger}
                                                    id='pin1'
                                                    className="auth-input-pin"
                                                onKeyUp={(event)=>this.enterPin(event,1)}
                                                    component={renderTextField}
                                            />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 mt-2">
                                            <Field name={'pin2'}
                                            maxLength={"1"}
                                            id='pin2'
                                            tabindex={1}
                                            className="auth-input-pin"
                                            normalize={isInteger}
                                            onKeyUp={(event)=>this.enterPin(event,2)}
                                                    component={renderTextField}
                                            />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 mt-2">
                                            <Field name={'pin3'}
                                            id='pin3'
                                            className="auth-input-pin"
                                            maxLength={"1"}
                                            normalize={isInteger}
                                            onKeyUp={(event)=>this.enterPin(event,3)}
                                                    component={renderTextField}
                                            />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 mt-2">
                                            <Field name={'pin4'}
                                            id='pin4'
                                            className="auth-input-pin"
                                            maxLength={"1"}
                                            normalize={isInteger}
                                            onKeyUp={(event)=>this.enterPin(event,4)}
                                                    component={renderTextField}
                                            />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 mt-2">
                                            <Field name={'pin5'}
                                            maxLength={"1"}
                                            id="pin5"
                                            className="auth-input-pin"
                                            normalize={isInteger}
                                            onKeyUp={(event)=>this.enterPin(event,5)}
                                                    component={renderTextField}
                                            />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 mt-2">
                                            <Field name={'pin6'}
                                            normalize={isInteger}
                                            id="pin6"
                                            className="auth-input-pin"
                                            maxLength={"1"}
                                            onKeyUp={(event)=>this.enterPin(event,6)}
                                                    component={renderTextField}
                                            />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Logic Part :

```
onSubmitHandler = (formProp) => {
// here i want to write logic
}
```

View : [image]

Comment: This will help you https://medium.com/@mohammad.nicoll/react-native-otp-input-6ec55850c0ab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React Refs for the `Feild` component to set focus.
Refer this for help - https://codepulse.blog/how-to-focus-element-in-react/